# Instantiating a interface CharSequence

Tags: java, interface, charsequence

```
CharSequence[] items = { “Google”, “Apple”, “Microsoft” };
```

if `CharSequence` is an interface then, in the above example aren't we instantiating a interface?

Comment: You are assigning initial values to an array of the **type** defined by an interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're instantiating a `String` array and then assigning it to variable that has a `CharSequence` array type. This works because `String` is assignable to (implements) `CharSequence`. Here's a couple more examples:

```
CharSequence cs = "Whatever";
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

So you're actually instantiating concrete types and assigning them to a variable/field that has an interface type.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar example using custom classes:

```
interface A{}

class A1 implements A{}

class A2 implements A{}

class A3 implements A{}

public class B {

    A[] items = {new A1(),new A2(), new A3()};

}
```

Here each object in `items` is actually of the implementing type (A1,A2,A3) rather than `A` itself.

In your example something like this would also have been possible:

```
CharSequence[] items = {"Google",new StringBuffer("Apple"), new StringBuilder("Microsoft")};
```

Answer (score -1):

CharSequence[] items = { “Google”, “Apple”, “Microsoft” };

Here only the declared type of the reference variable is an interface, which is alright.

But the objects in the array are String objects - whose class implements the CharSequence interface.

Say, CharSequence[] items = { new Charsequence() }   would result in compilation error

whereas

CharSequence[] items = { new someclass() }

where

class someclass implements CharSequence {

//

}

is totally fine

Comment: Can I please know the reason for the negative marking?

Comment: Just a guess but its probably the format of the text

Comment: But who would have down voted this? And why are they being silent? is this answer not helpful or not correct?